# Nexus 4 struck at google logo after flashing localy build ubuntu images

Tags: boot, ubuntu-touch, flash, nexus-4

Download the ubuntu-touch pahblet code base and build images for nexus 4 devices (mako) as mentioned in the site - https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/porting-new-device/.

Tried by flashing the locally generated boot.img and recovery.img. Flashing went successfull. Also flashed system.img and vivid-preinstalled-touch-armhf.tar.gz by using "rootstock-touch-install" script file . Flashing completed successfully.

But after reboot, nexus 4 device struct at "google logo" for long time . And also tried by flashing xenial tar file also. In both vivid/xenial cases , nexus 4 devices struck at google logo after flashing.

Is there any other flashing procedure available to successfully boot nexus-4 device with locally build images ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the standard installation process https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/ with the Ubuntu compiled image for the Nexus 4 is not an option for you?

Comment: I want to flash Nexus 4 device with locally build ubuntu-touch phablet source build images as mentioned in porting guide - https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/porting-new-device/ . But the suggested flashing method using "rootstock-touch-install" is not working .

Comment: Your best bet is to "Join the conversation on IRC in #ubuntu-touch on irc.freenode.net.", there you will find help.